# onResume is not called in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `activity` with `two fragments` in it

at some point i call `startActivity` for system activity, and when that system activity is over, my activity DOES get `onResume`, however, all the fragments in it DONT.

Why ?

PS. my activity is "singleInstance"

Comment: what? that is completely bogus, fragments are supposed to be attached to the life cycle, and textviews are not

Comment: if you read it well... fragments HAVE onResume, and that one is supposed to be called after the activity's onResume: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onResume`, for `Fragments` you should use `setUserVisibleHint` like:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        //onResume
    } else {
        //onPause
    }
}
```